# Ruby hash with duplicate keys to create URL parameters

Tags: ruby

I am using a hash for parameters to be used in generating a URL. I have something like this:

```
params = {
  :center => Geocoder.coordinates(currentlocation).join(","),
  :zoom => 10,
  :size => "460x280",
  :markers => Geocoder.coordinates(markerlocation).join(","),
  :sensor => true,
  :key => ENV["GOOGLE_API_KEY"]
  }

query_string =  params.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
image_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?#{query_string}", :alt => location
```

However I need to have multiple "markers" parameters in the URL. For each URL I generate I won't know how many "markers" parameters I need. For example if I have an array `markerlocations` I will need to create a `:markers` key-value pair for each member of the array for use in the URL. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'
params = {
  :center => Geocoder.coordinates(currentlocation).join(","),
  :zoom => 10,
  :size => "460x280",
  :markers => [Geocoder.coordinates(markerlocation).join(",")],
  :sensor => true,
  :key => ENV["GOOGLE_API_KEY"]
  }
query_string = URI.encode_www_form(params)
image_tag ...
```